# How to center a QDialog in QMdiSubWindow?

Tags: qt

I have a QDialog created from a QMdiSubWindow, when the Dialog shows up is centered on the MdiArea but I want it to be centered on his QMdiSubWindow parent instead. How do I achieve that?

Program screenshot

[image]

Comment: Is the `QMdiSubWindow` the parent of the `QDialog`?  If not you should try that.

Comment: yes when I create the QDialog I Iset the QMdiSubWindow as his parent

Comment: G.M. agregarEquipoForm *add = new agregarEquipoForm(this) agregarEquipo is my QDialog and "this" correspond to the QMdiSubWindow parent

Answer (score 0):

If QMdiSubWindow is the parent (parent) of QDialog (child), You can try this:

```
    p_w = parent.width()
    p_h = parent.height()
    pos_y = int((p_h - child.height()) / 2)
    pos_x = int((p_w - child.width()) / 2)
    child.move(pos_x, pos_y)
```

Comment: Ando:- For reasons unknown to me, when I try your solution, the QDialog moves outside of the QMainWindow area??

Comment: maybe, you need to set the parent?  "  dialog = QDialog(parent)  "